# Review count showing but no reviews awaiting

Tags: bug, review

Why am I being told there are reviews awaiting here:

[image]

When in fact there isn't:

[image]

I've just recently got access to mod tools so maybe I'm missing something but this does *seem* like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

Please read the canonical meta.see post:

[What does the number next to the review link in the top bar actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251659/154443)

The number is those outstanding overall, not necessarily those awaiting your input.

It does seem a bit odd but don't worry about it :-)

Comment: Should have known, thanks Rory.

Comment: It still confuses me, too, even after all this time ;)